# series question about summation

Tags: sequences-and-series

The sum of the summation, from $n = 0$ to $n = \infty$, for $\frac{e^{2n}x^n}{n!}$
I feel that it is $e^{e^{2x}}$ since $x^n/n!$ is the series for $e$. But it is not correct. Can anyone guide me through?

Answer (score 1):

According to Taylor's series for $e^u$:$$e^u=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{u^n\over n!}$$therefore$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{e^{2n}x^n}{n!}{=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(e^{2}x)^n}{n!}\\=e^{e^2x}\\\approx (1618.1780)^x}$$

Comment: I think you should add the step $=(e^{e^2})^x$ to be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{e^{2n}x^n}{n!}$$
Differentiate we get \begin{align*}f'(x)&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{e^{2n}x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{e^{2n+2}x^n}{n!}\\
&=e^2f(x) \end{align*}
So we have to solve ODE $f'(x)=e^2f(x)$ which is simply $$f(x)=Ae^{e^2x}$$
But from inspection we have $f(1)=e^{e^2}$, hence $$f(x)=e^{e^2x}.$$

Comment: thank you for your help, it is very clear!

Comment: Actually, I realize we can just use the Maclaurin Expansion to directly get the answer, it will equal $e^{e^2x}$, but I'm lazy to erase the solution!